# Issue with a column containing special characters

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have dataframe in R that contains a **column** of **type character** with values as follows

```
"\"121.29\""
"\"288.1\""
"\"120\""
"\"V132.3\""
"\"800\""
```

I am trying to get rid of the extra " and \ and retain clean values as below

```
121.29
288.10
120.00
V132.30
800.00
```

I tried `gsub("([\\])","", x)` also `str_repalce_all` function so far no luck. I would much appreciate it if anybody can help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
gsub('\\"',"",x)
[1] "121.29" "288.1"  "120"    "V132.3" "800"
```

Since the fourth entry is not numeric and an atomic vector can only contain entries of the same mode, the entries are all characters in this case (the most flexible mode capable of storing the data). So there still will be quotes around each entry.

Because `\` is a special character, it needs to be escaped with a backslash, so the expression `\\"` is passed as a first parameter to `gsub()`. Moreover, as suggested by @rawr, one can use single quotes to address the double quote. 
An alternative would be to use double quotes and escape them, too:

```
gsub("\\\"","",x)
```

which yields the same result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wouldn't just `gsub('"', "", '"\"800\""')` work (as @rawr mentioned already)?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, it would work. The answer you're suggesting is shorter by two characters. I prefer my suggestion because I find it clearer. It removes the backslashs rather than rendering them invisible in the output.

Comment: I don't think the back slashes are really there. It's just a print method. Try typing `'"800"'` in console.

Comment: It's not semantics, it used in order to escape characters. You can't just do `"\"` in R

Comment: You can, just as you suggested with `gsub('"', "", '"\"800\""')`, but I don't think that it makes much sense to keep such escape characters in a string if they're not escaping anything. That's why in my opinion the correct answer to this question consists in removing the backslashs, too.